# ADC scaling is off?

Tags: adc

I'm using a DAQ to do some ADC. It's has a 16 bit resolution, and that coverts to 32768 being 0v.

Currently, the data I have acquired looks like this: [image]

it has 8100 as 0v. Why is this? Could I just add 24668 to everything and shift it upwards? Then calculate the voltage measured using the shifted data?

(specific DAQ is the usb-1608fs from measurement computing: http://www.mccdaq.com/PDFs/Manuals/USB-1608FS.pdf
Analog specifications are on page 20)

edit: most EVERYTHING I capture with this DAQ is centered around 8100~

Comment: "... and that coverts to 32768 being 0v." Depends on how it's configured and everything around it.

Comment: I see you've added the kind of DAQ, I doubt a commercial unit has that much unexpected offset so it would be good to see a schematic or diagram of what it's connected to and how.

Comment: basically, its connected to my soundcard, where I play a sound, and then feeds the data back to my computer through an USB cable.

Comment: Sound cards are usually not DC coupled, so you will likely always get 8100 for a static signal..

Comment: Draw the circuit and post it is the best way to get a decent answer. Are you sure it's not a 14 bit system?

Comment: @Andyaka Hi Andy, like I said, it's just a closed loop where I connect the headphone jack of my laptop to the DAQ and then connect the DAQ back to my laptop. My laptop plays a sound for it to record. - Yes, the DAQ has a 16 bit resolution

Comment: @user36129, wait, so that means soundcards have AC output, so why would it have a static (DC?) signal? Also, why is it 8100? (-1.24 volts)

Comment: @sam the output is capacitor coupled, so when it is not outputting a signal, it will settle to some value determined by the capacity on the line and the value of the coupling capacitor, and maybe some biasing network. No real way to say how it exactly works in your case without cracking it open and having a look at the circuit, but suffice it to say that you will not be able to get DC measurements with this kind of an ADC.

Comment: @user36129 I see... so that means the static signal is not part of the output, and therefore I CAN shift the entire waveform upwards by adding 32768.